# Particle cache step of less than 1?

Tags: particles, cache

I have a particle system, and an emitter. Sometimes the emitter moves extremely fast, and leaves gaps between particles.
I'd like to lower the Cache Step below 1, is there any way I can have blender output more particles? (Kinda like having an FPS of 60/120, but only playing every 2/4 frames.)

[image: particle Cache settings]